# How to load a custom font locally into a symfony project?

Tags: symfony, fonts, webpack-encore

I want to load IMG Plex font into a symfony project with webpack encore.

I imported it into my scss file:

```
@import "../fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf";
```

But nothing changed. Only the cdn worked for me.

And yes I did not forgot to restart yarn encore dev --watch

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: 99% the relative path is just not matching to where the files get stored, use an absolute path like `/public/build/fontsIBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf`

Comment: Oh - webpack dont build that. I have only the IBM_Plex_Sans folder in my assets directory ...

Comment: Ok - now I added the fonts folder to my public folder in symfony and did it like u said. Did not work. Instead - webpack gives me now an error and said 
File to import not found or unreadable: /public/fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to import ttf files in your sccs.
In scss you have to import @font-face:

An example:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'IBM_Plex_Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf');
}
```

Better yet, add a few other font formats (woff,woff2,eot  etc.)

Comment: Did not work. I tried it the path is correct. Also phpstorm accept it. 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/ibm-plex-sans-v7-latin/ibm-plex-sans-v7-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('IBM Plex Sans'), local('IBMPlexSans'),

Answer (score 0):

You can store your font files in

```
asset/styles/fonts/YOURFONTNAME/YOURFONT.ttf
```

With

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YOURFONTNAME';
    src: 
        url('./fonts/YOURFONTNAME/YOURFONT.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```